# `rules` or `except` which is best practice to use in GitLab pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, git-tag

Need an advice for very big enterprise I am reviewing their CI pipeline and there some jobs which has got `except` and `only`, and I am wondering is `rules` better practice or not.

One of the job looks like below:

```
hadolint:
  extends: [".hadolint"]
  except:
    - tags

compile:
  extends: [".compile"]
  except:
    - tags

unit-test:
  extends: [".unit-test"]
  except:
    - tags
```

And I am thinking it to change like below:

```
hadolint:
  extends: [".hadolint"]
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
      when: never
    - when: always

compile:
  extends: [".compile"]
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
      when: never
    - when: always

unit-test:
  extends: [".unit-test"]
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
      when: never
    - when: always
```

Any advise would be appreciated, have gone through [GitLab doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html) as well, but they have just mentioned the usage not which one is better

Answer (score 0):

They're equally "right", and there isn't one that's better as opposed to the other. It's worth knowing, however, that `rules` is a newer syntax and sees more extension than the other two. If you want to define more complex logic for when jobs run, you will *need* to use the rules keyword. If you're OK with the simple logic, then `except` or `only` are fine.

Comment: Thanks, does make sense. Will use ‘rules’ so if I need complex condition in future that would be handy and don’t have to change the keyword.